# iOS 8 geolocation error web browser iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, geolocation

my application is a UIWebView in fullscreen and i load a website. My website is based on the geolocation of the user. Before, my app is working fine for any device but since iOS 8 it doesn't work on iphone 6 and 6 plus. I was forced to add permissions in plist file.

The added keys is: -NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription -NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription -NSLocationUsageDescription

After, my app work with iphone 6 but NOT with the iPhone 6 Plus... WHY ?

I have also check in scheme for be sure Allow Location Simulation is checked...

I have search a lot and i have try a lot of solutions and nothing works...

My geolocation is on my website with JS so i dont have locationManager...

I have only a UIWebview, ViewController and AppDelegate in my project.

If i try my website with safari in iphone 6 plus it working but not in application...

I have check in setting and my app is always authorize to get the location

Some have a idea why it doesn't work on 6 PLUS ?

Thx for help